# Multivariate Linear Regression in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, regression, linear-regression

I have a vector A[a1, a2, a3] and B[b1, b2, b3]. I want to find a "correlation" matrix X (3x3) that can predict from new incoming data of A' to to produce output predictions of B'. Basically in the end: A'*X to get B'.

I have lots of recorded data of A and B (paired). Based on an answer below (and I agree), I think this is Multivariate Linear Regression. I think there should be common libraries doing this, but I don't understand enough of multivariate linear regression to implement them. Nor do I know which algorithm and library to use.

Given that,

```
b1 = x1_1*a1 + x2_1*a2 + x3_1*a3 + e1
b2 = x1_2*a1 + x2_2*a2 + x3_2*a3 + e2
b3 = x3_1*a1 + x3_2*a2 + x3_3*a3 + e3
```

Would it make sense to do multiple linear regression on each, and combine the solution together? If not, why not?

Comment: I'm no expert in this field, however have you looked at solving the problem Ax = B by Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). If you have MATLAB available there is a built-in [SVD method](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/svd.html). (Octave might have one too).

Comment: Sorry for being broad on the question, because at this point I still understand only at a very high level of the problem. I don't yet have a concrete approach in my head. Hence, any further advice would be more than appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a multiple regression, but a multivariate regression. Basically this can be viewed as if one was to estimate three multiple regression models

```
b1 = t1_1* a1 + t2_1 * a2 + t3_1 * a3 + e1
b2 = t1_2* a1 + t2_2 * a2 + t3_2 * a3 + e2
b3 = t3_1* a1 + t3_2 * a2 + t3_3 * a3 + e3
```

but he wants to take into account correlations in b1, b2, b3 when doing simultaneous tests for b's statistical significance. Because the matrix of model coefficients will be same if you estimated each model separately as if you estimated multivariate model, you can just estimate each model ( for each b) separately and combine results into matrix A. You won't just get multivariate tests. They are helpful but if you are interested simply in quantitative relationship you can skip them. Or you can write them by yourself, look at [F-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test), MANOVA.

[Multivariate regression](http://www.psych.yorku.ca/lab/psy6140/lectures/MultivariateRegression2x2.pdf)

You can find help in [dlib](http://dlib.net/), [dlib](http://dlib.net/svr_ex.cpp.html), [gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multi_002dparameter-fitting.html).

Comment: In the example, I can see that if we want multiple variables input, we change the sample_type to matrix<double,3,1>. But how do we get to have multiple variables for targets? and what else would need to change from the example?

Comment: you can start from [gsl]( http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multi_002dparameter-fitting.html)

Comment: okay will start on that. Quick question, would it not make sense to just do do the three multiple regress models? and combine the answer into a matrix?

Comment: @HaikalPribadi you can do it, you will get same coefficients for each separate model as if you were estimating multivariate regression, you won't just get multivariate tests

Comment: how important are the multivariate tests?

Comment: it is totally dependent on your view, I guess you can omit them at the moment, back to the topic if regression results will be spurious

Comment: @HaikalPribadi is there something more I can explain?

Comment: This is a good start, seems to be what I need. Although I'm going with MLPACK instead of DLIB. They seem to be more easily understandable. Thanks!