# Performing Multivariate Linear Regression in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, linear-regression, least-squares

I am looking for a way to perform a (medium-scale*) **multivariate linear regression (ordinary least-squares, OLS) in C++**. Say C++11 with using `std` library, and if helpful also `boost`; if easily installable also the use of further libraries is fine; use of e.g. `std::vector` format for inputs & outputs could be most convenient.

Performance is not top priority, though of course appreciated.

What does a reasonable algorithm look like? Are there any good tools readily available to help with it?

Various implementations for *univariate* regression algos can readily be found, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18939869/3673329), but I have not yet found any multivariate version. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23860821/3673329) question essentially asks for such a regression though it has been closed due to lack of focus, even if it's title would be the ideal one.

**Medium-scale: in my case e.g. say few ten-thousands of observations, and up to hundred explanatories/attributes (e.g. time-dummies).*

Comment: the question you link has an accepted answer, so why does it matter that it is closed?

Comment: The standard algorithm (for instance used by R) consists in computing the QR decomposition of the design matrix. There are plenty of online university courses on applying the QR to linear regression. As to an implementation, I would suggest LAPACK and a C binding. You may also use Intel MKL (which is free and works well on Intel processors). Implementing a straightforward QR algorithm (Householder for instance) is reasonably easy, but taking care of the memory cache by using block matrix computations is more challenging.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I wonder whether implementations in C++ already exist.

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971989/thin-qr-decomposition-in-c), [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) can compute the QR decomposition.